# receive audio form a user with discord bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord project and in that project i need to record a user voice, i'm following [this](https://discordjs.guide/voice/receiving-audio.html#basic-usage) document.

so far this is what i wrote:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === 'a' && message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const audio = connection.receiver.createStream('user_id?', { mode: 'pcm' });
        audio.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('user_audio'));
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

but the problem is that always the user_audio file is empty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in discord.js, to solve this problem we need to play an audio...

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const { Readable } = require('stream');

const SILENCE_FRAME = Buffer.from([0xF8, 0xFF, 0xFE]);

class Silence extends Readable {
  _read() {
    this.push(SILENCE_FRAME);
    this.destroy();
  }
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.content === 's' && message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const audio = connection.receiver.createStream(message, { mode: 'pcm', end: 'manual' });
        audio.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('user_audio'));

        connection.play(new Silence(), { type: 'opus' });
        console.log(message.member.user.id);
    }
});

client.login('token');
```

Comment: This does not work in discord.js v14:
`channel.join()` and `connection.play(...)` have been removed. Intents should also be specified. Good answer for v13, though